Image isn't loading from url using AsyncImage
I'm making a college project and had some troubles using AsyncImage for load a picture from an URL, here is the code that is not working:
AsyncImage(
                model = plant.imageUrl,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp)
            )

The data class is:
package data

data class Plant(
    val description: String,
    val growZoneNumber: Int,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val name: String,
    val plantId: String,
    val wateringInterval: Int
)

That is read from a Json file, here is an example:
{
    "plantId": "malus-pumila",
    "name": "Apple",
    "description": "An apple is a sweet, edible fruit produced by an apple tree (Malus pumila). Apple trees are cultivated worldwide, and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. The tree originated in Central Asia, where its wild ancestor, Malus sieversii, is still found today. Apples have been grown for thousands of years in Asia and Europe, and were brought to North America by European colonists. Apples have religious and mythological significance in many cultures, including Norse, Greek and European Christian traditions.<br><br>Apple trees are large if grown from seed. Generally apple cultivars are propagated by grafting onto rootstocks, which control the size of the resulting tree. There are more than 7,500 known cultivars of apples, resulting in a range of desired characteristics. Different cultivars are bred for various tastes and uses, including cooking, eating raw and cider production. Trees and fruit are prone to a number of fungal, bacterial and pest problems, which can be controlled by a number of organic and non-organic means. In 2010, the fruit's genome was sequenced as part of research on disease control and selective breeding in apple production.<br><br>Worldwide production of apples in 2014 was 84.6 million tonnes, with China accounting for 48% of the total.<br><br>(From <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple\">Wikipedia</a>)",
    "growZoneNumber": 3,
    "wateringInterval": 30,
    "imageUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Apple_orchard_in_Tasmania.jpg"
  }

For some reason the picture is not loading leaving a gray space. I checked that all values are read correctly, may be the URL, but I'm not experience enough for knowing what it is. I used AsyncImage previously and it works with this URL:
https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/81/202627.jpg

Have you confirmed your image url loads appropriately? And that your internet connection is good?

Please also verify that, when calling AsyncImage, plant.imageUrl really contains what you expect it to contain.
